# how to set all links in iframe to "google.com" by javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, hyperlink

how to set all links in iframe to "google.com" by javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: Is the iframe from the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: If it is not the same domain you can not do it. It is a security measure that all the major browsers implement. Else you could do things like show people their homebanking page in an iFrame and then redirect the login information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the iframe's `contentWindow` attribute to get a hold on the global object running in the iframe.  From there you can do what you want.

```
$(iframe.contentWindow).find("a").each(function(){
  //replace url
})
```

But if url of the iframe is on another domain, this will trigger a XSS (cross server scripting) error and you won't be able to access the window dom.  This is a security feature, so it cannot be circumvented.  In other words, you cannot to that.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in iframe

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/" + $("a").attr("href"))
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n97yK/)

---

**EDIT**

If you need to replace the domain links with google.com, use this

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var pathname = $(this)[0].pathname;
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com" + pathname);
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n97yK/2/)